Serilog miss some logs in multiple instances environment
My environment is multi-instances.
Here is the code logic:

Reading a file(contain 15k of entries) -> insert into queue-A respectively with entry ID
Instance pick up one entry from queue-A -> create a record in DB, log it no matter successful or fail. -> insert into queue-B with entry ID
Instance pick up one entry from queue-B -> create a property-X for this record in DB, log it no matter successful or fail. -> insert into queue-C with property ID
Instance pick up one entry from queue-C -> create a property-Y for this record in DB, log it no matter successful or fail.
The flow is sequential.

When we check Datadog, we found some entries log are missing in step 2 and 3. They don't have either successful and fail log. They are created in DB, only logs are missing.
Assumption:

Is it because Serilog doesn't write properly due to multi-instance environment? No we have set in Serilog setting. <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.shared" value="true"/>, Also I can see different instances can write logs into the same file.

Does the log reach the line/file limit? No, If we use Serilog Async then buffer size feeding Async() is fixed at 10,000 items by default, and does not block when full. In each log, there are about 3-14k of records, it is not big.

Does it CPU usage too high and cannot process? No, it is about 20% usage.

Is it because Datadog miss some log files? No, our log file has formatted name File-Data-sequentialNumber. I can see a certain of continuous number in the files.


Obervation:

In Prod environment there are 60 logs missing in step 2 and 60 logs missing in step 3 over 12k of entries.
In NFT environment, there are about 1/4 of records missing in both step 2 and step 3. It is just about process every 4 records and miss 1 log, sometimes process every 3 records and miss 1 log. The pattern is stable in relatively time frame.

Can anyone help me to identify Why it miss logs?

is this the File or the RollingFile sink? You don't want to be on an unmaintained sink that very few people are using. For starters it narrows the pool of people that might be able to provide a relevant answer here. Having said that, I've no particular reason to expect that any specific issue has been fixed - the File and Async sinks have historicaly had significant usage so I'd be surprised if there was an outright bug that would drop messages, even if it was an older version

@RubenBartelink In my project it uses both File and RollingFile. In my case, I would firstly add more logs to see whether it drops message. If it doesn't help I will upgrade to the latest version.

If you can consolidate on the latest versions of the packages, then you can read the  source and/or repost your question stating the version and your config wiring as it sounds pretty typical so someone might be able to suggest ideas of things to check from there. To eliminate the Async Sink from your inquiries, you could hook into the buffer monitoring APIs, put it in blocking mode, or make the limit even higher

@RubenBartelink Thanks, I will do it. And I don't use Async Sink.

Finally we found the reason, it is the DataDog issue.

There are 2 background nodes/instance haven't been read by DataDog.
Some of the logs have been written into another services. Those logs appear as "event attribute" in DataDog rather than log message. Hence, those logs can't be queried.

